# Showing images of large area in website with thousands of large aerial images hosted on remote server

Tags: geoserver, wms, web-mapping, mapserver, tile-server

To be able to use TMS service using GDAL2TIle, one has to make a mosaic of all of images first which is impractical given the fact that there are thousands of aerial images, each 3500x3500px large.

**Is there any other solution to use TMS or WMS services without creating a mosaic of the whole aerial images first?**

If not, then how it that even possible that we have a layer in [OSM-iD](https://www.openstreetmap.org/login?referer=%2Fedit) for the NRW or Bavaria in Germany consisting of a large number of aerial images or even the whole world in the aerial Bing layer. It is unbelievable that all those images were merged to create a mosaic and then tiled to be able to use either TMS or WMS service.

Comment: GeoServer users create a virtual mosaic with https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html, MapServer users do the same with tileindex https://mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html. GDAL users use gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With big data sets the image mosaics are usually virtual. There is some data structure that is like a table of contents or image index that tell where to find the original images.

GeoServer users create a virtual mosaic with https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html, MapServer users do the same with tileindex https://mapserver.org/optimization/tileindex.html. GDAL users use gdalbuildvrt https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

The formats of image indexes vary. GDAL VRT is using XML, MapServer and GeoServer are using shapefile or some other supported GIS vector format.